# Unable to install PyTorch in Windows 10

Tags: python, gpu

I want to install python torch in windows 10. I am following the instructions from the official website https://pytorch.org/.
[pytorch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DjfW.png)

when I run the above commands I get the following error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa9L8.png)

I have attached the GPU details.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qZ6S.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste the error, so it's easier to read and searchable.